# ¿Cómo hacer un wrapper en C++ pre 11 de una estructura POD hecha en C99?

Tags: c++, c

Muy buenas. En primer lugar, puede que la pregunta no tenga el formato correcto. Iré editándola conforme vaya añadiendo más información o vea que en los comentarios muestren una falta de información o estructura.

Tengo una estructura realizada en POD, en C99.

Pondré un ejemplo de qué tipo de estructura suelo encontrarme a la que me interesa hacerle un wrapper (extraída amablemente desde Freetype 2.4.4):

```
  typedef enum  BDF_PropertyType_
  {
    BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_NONE     = 0,
    BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_ATOM     = 1,
    BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_INTEGER  = 2,
    BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_CARDINAL = 3

  } BDF_PropertyType;
  typedef struct  BDF_PropertyRec_
  {
    BDF_PropertyType  type;
    union {
      const char*     atom;
      FT_Int32        integer;
      FT_UInt32       cardinal;

    } u;

  } BDF_PropertyRec;
```

Mi pregunta es: **¿cómo consigo hacerle un wrapper en C++98 a estructuras interconectadas?**

Me planteé hacer una clase que utilizase un `BDF_PropertyRec`, pero utilizando como objeto privado y utilizarla, pero sigo dependiendo de `malloc` y `free` para su ciclo de vida, desechando la idea rápidamente por tener que mantener en memoria ambos objetos, como hacen aquí: https://os.mbed.com/questions/241/How-to-wrap-C-functions-into-C-class/

Aquí, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17454763/8607301, aplican una forma del tipo herencia para lograr un wrapper. No veo cómo lograrlo con estructuras de POD o de datos clásicos que tengan punteros conectados a otras estructuras, o un vector de dichos elementos dados por el puntero base y la longitud máxima, algo como esto:

```
typedef struct  t_Elementos_utilizados
{
  uint8_t   valor1;
  uint16_t  valor2;
  uint8_t   valor3;
  uint32_t  valor4;
} * Elementos_utilizados; // ¡ojito al elemento puntero, aquí hay trampa!

typedef struct  t_Estructura_POD_con_vectores
{
  uint32_t elementos;
  Elementos_utilizados vector; // ¡Esto tiene trampa, lee bien la definición del typedef anterior!

} Estructura_POD_con_vectores; //< ¿Cómo enganchar esto en una clase?
```

En Software Engineering (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/181587/296879) comentan utilizar façades o `std::make_unique`. En el caso de C++98, `std::make_unique` no sirve (habría que insertar la extensión TR1 o utilizar boost, y por ahora, eso no es viable), y un patrón façade agrega demasiadas capas para acceder a los elementos de dicho vector, dificultando el encapsulado (una capa para la primera estructura, otra para la segunda, y una de comunicación entre ambas, dejando la estructura original duplicada, pero no veo que sea accesible sin copias).

Según he estado leyendo en C++ Coding Standards - 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices, de Herb Sutter y Andrei Alexandrescu, recomienda utilizar RAIIs (recomendación 13), que implica duplicar y tener que mantener ambos objetos, el de la estructura y el objeto C++ convertido.

Repito la pregunta: ¿Cómo hacer un wrapper en C++98 (¡obsoleto!) a una estructura conectada con otras en C99?

Answer (score 2):

No existe una única forma de hacer un wrapper. Hay muchos aspectos a tener en cuenta:

- Necesidades del proyecto.
- Recursos disponibles (tiempo, dinero, personal).
- Estado del arte (no es lo mismo encarar un proyecto de 0 que uno ya existente).
- Gustos personales del equipo de desarrollo.

Como has comentado el wrapper puede desarrollarse por herencia. Esta solución es facil de aplicar:

```
class MyBDF_PropertyRec : public BDF_PropertyRec
{
public:
  MyBDF_PropertyRec()
  {
    type = BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_NONE;
  }

  void SetValue(char const* atom)
  {
    type = BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_ATOM;
    u.atom = atom;
  }

  void SetValue(int value)
  {
    type = BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_INTEGER;
    u.integer = value;
  }
};
```

Pero tiene como principal inconveniente que la estructura de C es visible en todo momento, por lo que se pueden manipular su estructura interna:

```
MyBDF_PropertyRec propertyRec;
propertyRec.type = BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_INTEGER;
property.u.atom = "abcdef";
```

En vez de herencia se puede optar por la composición, pero entonces el diseño se puede complicar ya que esta solución nos puede obligar a repetir funcionalidad (no es el caso de este ejemplo):

```
class PropertyRec 
{
  BDF_PropertyRec data;

public:
  PropertyRec()
  {
    data.type = BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_NONE;
  }

  void SetValue(char const* atom)
  {
    data.type = BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_ATOM;
    data.u.atom = atom;
  }

  void SetValue(int value)
  {
    data.type = BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_INTEGER;
    data.u.integer = value;
  }

  BDF_PropertyRec GetBDFPropertyRec() const
  { return data; }
};
```

Y esto son solo dos opciones dentro del extenso abanico de posibilidades. Llegando a casos extremos se podría crear un wrapper completo de la librería. En este caso la librería en C quedaría completamente oculta y el programador solo vería una capa C++. Esta opción es, obviamente, la más costosa ya que requiere construir toda la interfaz en C++.

```
class PropertyRec
{
  std::variant<std::string,int,unsigned int> value;

public:
  void SetValue(std::string const& atom)
  {
    value = atom;
  }

  void SetValue(int intValue)
  {
    value = intValue;
  }
};

namespace BDFUtils
{
  PropertyRec GetProperty(Face const& face, std::string const& propertyName)
  {
    BDF_PropertyRec property;
    FT_Face ftFace = /* ... */
    FT_Get_BDF_Property(face,
                        propertyName.c_str(),
                        &property );

    PropertyRec toReturn;

    switch( property.type )
    {
      case BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_ATOM:
        toReturn.SetValue(std::string(property.u.atom));
        break;

      case BDF_PROPERTY_TYPE_INTEGER:
        toReturn.SetValue(property.u.integer);
        break;

      // ...
    }

    return propertyRec;
  }
}
```

Comment: Precisamente, en la parte inicial, no hay problema, puesto que de cualesquiera de las opciones, puedes buscar la que más o menos dificultad tenga a la hora de implementar.

El problema viene cuando hay varias estructuras anidadas la una con la otra, como pongo en el segundo snippet de código. Ahí no veo una forma clara o limpia de poder implementarlo sin montar un desastre

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos nada te impide montar una estructura paralela en C++  que cubra tus necesidades... solo tienes que diseñar un mecanismo que permita convertir la estructura C++ en la estructura que espera la librería

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos, también puede usarse un operador de conversión al usar composición. T operator(), que te permite usar la estructura con C.